# how to make this program can accept the negative number

Tags: c, floating-point

I make this code and then the code cant accept the -1 number. If i input -1 number the code will break. i want to make if the accept the -1 number the 
 total variable will be + zero and then the n will be minus by 1

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float n, x, total = 0;
    scanf("%f",&n);
    if(n>=1 && n<=100){
        for(int a=1;a<=n;a++){
            scanf("%f",&x);
            if(x>=-1 && x<=4){
                if(x>=0){
                    total=total+x;
                } else {
                    total+=0;
                    n--;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%.3f",total/n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will be better if you provide properly indented code.

Comment: (properly indented code)

Comment: The literals, like 0, -1 and 4 and 1 and 100 are integers.  Suggest using: 0.0f, -1.0f, 4.0f, 1.0f, and 100.0f

Comment: Note: float values cannot exactly represent all integer values, so suggest including a (small) fudge factor when comparing to a value in a variable

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%f",&n);
    
    if(n>=1 && n<=100)`  how is the user expected to know the allowed range for that input is 1...100?   Suggest outputting a prompt similar to: `puts( "input a value in the range 1...100 inclusive");`

Comment: regarding: `for(int a=1;a<=n;a++)`  This is making comparisons between an integer and a float.  Suggest correcting

Comment: regarding: `if(x>=-1 && x<=4)`   The expression: `x>= -1` is probably failing when the actual input value is `-1.0f`

Answer (score -1):

you can add this condition like  if(x==-1) then total=0 and n--.

Comment: Never compare a float value for equality.